# Node-Red-Dashboard UI_Gauge on RPi3 / Ubuntu Mate 16.04 does not change with payload

Tags: node.js, dashboard, node-red

I have the problem that my UI_Gauge does not change with a changing payload. I used the debug node to check if the value is actually changing (it is), also I send a text info as value format which changes correctly.

This functionality do I expect:

```
If payload = 2, donut colour = red
If payload = 1, donut colour = green
```

Min value is 1, Max value is 2. But the colour does not change at all. Any ideas? NPM version is 3.5.2. Node.js is v4.2.6, Node-Red v0.18.6. Dashboard version is 2.9.3

Comment: You'll need to provide some more specific details about your flow, otherwise we cannot say why it isn't working as you expect

Comment: Flow before the node is `if (context.use == 2){
    msg.stat = "in use";
    msg.payload = 2;
    return msg;}
else{
    msg.payload = 1;
    msg.stat= "free";}
return msg;` I found out, that if I use a value format as {{value}} instead of {{stat}} it works. But I did not have the problem before on a different machine. I

Comment: I want to display a text as a label and not the value responsible for the colour change.